# CouchDB with java language

Tags: java, database, couchdb

I have some problems with couchDB in eclipse.I want to write in java to connect a couchDB database but I have no example and I did not find anywhere to help me!I need to add jar file to eclipse but I could not configure the problem.if you have an example can you sent to me? Thanks!
pc:My english is bad sorry:(

Comment: Looking for a CouchDB Java tutorial? Have you tried to google for _CouchDB Java tutorial_?

Comment: You can also just make pure HTTP calls to work with CouchDB.  You don't have to have a driver for Java.

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API

You can always use curl to do some simple testing before writing a ton of code.